# Asterisk fails to accept incoming calls

Tags: asterisk

I have configured a local Asterisk server. There are local users and a single  trunk for external calls.

Users can successfully make local and outgoing calls.
However when external calls come to the server, it responds with 401 error (1.1.1.1 stands for provider IP, 2.2.2.2 for local server's).

**Invite:**

```
<--- Received SIP request (1079 bytes) from UDP:1.1.1.1:5060 --->
INVITE sip:4959814263@192.168.50.2:5060 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 1.1.1.1:5060;branch=z9hG4bK2b074f13;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
From: <sip:84999228957@1.1.1.1>;tag=as5b4c0767
To: <sip:4959814263@192.168.50.2:5060>
Contact: <sip:84999228957@1.1.1.1:5060>
Call-ID: 7d18db7538627a5536e0e5423774e35c@1.1.1.1:5060
CSeq: 105 INVITE
User-Agent: VoIPVTK
Authorization: Digest username="s", realm="asterisk", algorithm=MD5, uri="sip:4959814263@2.2.2.2", nonce="1617646804/4c072b7aa1d5799d84d11f1e857387a0", response="7e12bdf0955235437f8d49fee0fc517a", opaque="1d4bee854523cdda", qop=auth, cnonce="3c7da01c", nc=00000003
Date: Mon, 05 Apr 2021 18:20:04 GMT
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 226

v=0
o=VoIPVTK 1371915978 1371915981 IN IP4 1.1.1.1
s=VoIPVTK
c=IN IP4 1.1.1.1
t=0 0
m=audio 11250 RTP/AVP 8 101
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=ptime:20
a=sendrecv
```

**Response:**

```
[Apr  5 21:20:04] NOTICE[72898]: res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c:676 log_failed_request: Request 'INVITE' from '<sip:84999228957@1.1.1.1>' failed for '1.1.1.1:5060' (callid: 7d18db7538627a5536e0e5423774e35c@1.1.1.1:5060) - Failed to authenticate
<--- Transmitting SIP response (502 bytes) to UDP:1.1.1.1:5060 --->
SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 1.1.1.1:5060;rport=5060;received=1.1.1.1;branch=z9hG4bK2b074f13
Call-ID: 7d18db7538627a5536e0e5423774e35c@1.1.1.1:5060
From: <sip:84999228957@1.1.1.1>;tag=as5b4c0767
To: <sip:4959814263@192.168.50.2>;tag=z9hG4bK2b074f13
CSeq: 105 INVITE
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="asterisk",nonce="1617646804/4c072b7aa1d5799d84d11f1e857387a0",opaque="52b0860022fc8faa",algorithm=md5,qop="auth"
Server: Asterisk PBX 18.2.0
Content-Length:  0
```

Also provider sends OPTIONS requests which fail with the same error too. OPTIONS requests from our server succeed.

It seems that provider sends packets without authorization, while server requires it.

How this can be settled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding
`registration/contact_user = 123456789 ;phone number or other contact info, provided by ISTP`
to trunk config (wizard type).

For non-wizard:

```
[trunk-name]
type=registration
contact_user = 123456789 ;phone number for incoming calls or other contact info, provided by ISTP
```

After this was done, our registration info at ISTP changed from `s@1.1.1.1:5060` to `123456789@1.1.1.1:5060`

Comment: Please take into account that I first installed Asterisk a week ago, so I am completely fresh noob there. Bear with me. :)